# Review task queue system

Tags: architecture

I'm implementing a review system, where users upload data items that need to be reviewed, and reviewers review it and provide comments. Each data item needs to be reviewed by 3 reviewers.

Items should be processed more or less in order - ideally item A would be added to the system, and reviewers 1,2 and 3 review it and it is returned to the user. Then item B is added to the system, reviewers 2,5,1 review it, and so on. Of course, since reviewers can work concurrently, and there are more than 3 reviewers, the system should support multiple items reviewed concurrently (by different reviewers, of course).

I'm not sure how to implement the data item repository. The requirements are:

- Items are added by multiple writers.
- Each item is read by 3 different readers.
- When a reader takes an item, it should take the first item that reader hasn't seen first.

I can implement all this using an SQL database, but it won't scale very well.

Is there an off-the-shelf queuing system that supports something like this (basically, popping the first item that doesn't fit a criteria)? Or some way of adding this to an existing queuing system?

Comment: This is a very non-specific question, and hard to answer. Are you looking for us to tell you exactly how to do this in Django? Cause that basically means we'll have to teach you how to use Django.

Comment: No, no, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Given that SQL databases underlie many enterprise-scale systems, I see no basis for the "it won't scale very well" statement. It's true that large-scale enterprise systems benefit from dedicated queueing systems, but these systems are dealing with, for example, all the transactions to be processed in a day by retail banks. I am sceptical that you can have so many items to be reviewed and so many concurrent reviewers that this requirement would stress a standard SQL database - 6,000 reviewers processing 60 items an hour would give only a few hundred tps. Of course I'm guessing as to the scale of your requirements, so it might be interesting to hear what they are.

However, I can see the conceptual merits of implementing this as a set of queues, a principle requirement then being the ability to "give me the next item from this queue that I have not already reviewed".

JMS selectors allow you to select records based on header field contents, so adding Reviewer1, and Reviewer2 header fields to your message should allow efficient selection of the next available item. Hence I'd guess that any JMS-complient queuing system would be sufficient.

Comment: SQL databases make very poor queue managers. That's why enterprise-scale systems use enterprise-scale queue management systems.

Comment: Good idea, regarding the JMS system.

Comment: I'll expand my thought about SQL DB for this problem

Comment: Now it's a matter of budget. If I buy an enterprise Oracle license and install it on fancy-enough hardware, it will be able to handle the queue load I'm predicting. I am not going to do any of that, I'll use a free PostgreSQL database on a relatively cheap virtual server. It's going to be cheaper to use a proper queuing system than to buff the database up until it can match the performance of a proper queuing system.